# Is it possible to run php code at asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, php, html, asp.net

Is it possible to use some php code in asp.net while using c# in background.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="MeineWebseite.löschen.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


<?php
echo "Hallo \"Welt\"";
echo $name;
echo " - i'am feeling fine";

function ausgabe ($wert) 
{ 
  echo $wert; 
}
?>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to  use php like this way. Which package should I install?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: yes, I did it! I tried to use peachpie, but it didnt work so like I want

Comment: You cannot just mix two languages. For starters, pick one language and learn how to write simple programs with it. After a while, you may look at other languages and then see the pros and cons of each of them.

Comment: ok! I understand it now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as it is concerned running `PHP` projects under `IIS`, it is possible to achieve, here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012785/4308286) on SO that might help in this regard.

But if you want to mix up ASP.NET C# and PHP code then I suppose it is not possible. The real question is, why on earth would you want to go this way? Is there something PHP can do and C# cannot? To me, C# seems way more elegant than PHP, why would you want to do it anyway?

As far as it is concerned being able to echo some data on front-end you can do that in C# like this (or using many other ways that might suit your scenario):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="MeineWebseite.löschen.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltEchos"/> <!-- Would share a sample to use this control to populate things -->
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`.CS` Code Behind:

```
public void EchoSomeDataWithResponseWrite()
{
    Response.Write("Hallo \"Welt\""); // echo, that does not involves the Literal control
    //  to give a line break, put your html like below
    Response.Write("<br />");
    var name = "John Doe"; // to write name
    Response.Write(name);

    // to write some raw script:
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Weather is fine today!')</script>");
}

public void EchoSomeDataWithLiteralControl()
{
    var name = "John Doe";
    var html = "Hallo \"Welt\" <br /> "; 
    html += name + "<br />";

    ltEchose.Text = html;
}
```

Power is in your hand, you can achieve anything using C# that you could've achieved using PHP.

Comment: Many people nowerdays use PHP and its easy to use it sofar I know. Until now Ive worked with c# but I tried to display images form folder randomly but I couldnt do it, but I saw in internet many examples with PHP

Comment: You can find many examples to display images using C# as well. There is way lot of helping material over the world wide web.